# rsync/ssh/rsnapshot backup -- remote script execution

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I have the following settings in my configuration file: (/etc/rsnapshot.conf)

Script/Tool: http://www.rsnapshot.org/

```
backup_script   ssh     root@host.domain.com "sh /home/user/backup_mysql.sh"     ./mysql
```

the example shows the following:

```
backup_script  ssh root@example.com "mysqldump -A > /var/db/dump/mysql.sql"    unused2
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR: backup_script /usr/bin/ssh returned 255
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which configuration file?

Comment: /etc/rsnapshot.conf

Comment: There's some key information missing here -- at first glance: (1) We have no idea what `configuration file` is (what program are you configuring?) ; (2) We have no idea what `backup_script` is doing. ; (3) What happens when you try running the ssh portion of the process manually? -- can you update your question to tell us more about what you're trying to do?  (See Also: [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: is 'backup_script' executable?

Comment: [Dirvish](http://dirvish.org) is excellent for this: it allows pre- and post- execution scripts on the server and the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be converting `ssh     root@host.domain.com "sh /home/user/backup_mysql.sh"` into a script (do_ssh.sh,here) and invoke that script.

Something like,

> backup_script   /path/to/do_ssh.sh     ./mysql

I'd also recommend you to try putting  quotes around your entire command.

> backup_script   "ssh     root@host.domain.com "sh
>   /home/user/backup_mysql.sh""     ./mysql

Comment: The first trick worked.

Answer (score 3):

rsnapshot configuration files are tab delimited. Make sure you include `tabs` between the backup_scrip, the ssh command, and the backup storage. If that does not work try running `rsnapshot configtest` to identify the problem.

Answer updated

It is more convenient to transform your backup line to the following format:

```
 backup_script    /dir/yourscript.sh    backupdirectory/
```

Place the middle section in a shell script, make it executable and test it.
In addition to this, the `ssh root@host.domain.com` should connect to the remote host without a password non-interactively.

Comment: yea, nothing wrong with tabs or config file

Answer (score 2):

The `rsnapshot.conf` example actually uses `backup_exec`, not `backup_script`. However, `backup_script` can still be used to run arbitrary commands over ssh and sync any files generated in a temp directory. Any commands used must be referenced by absolute path. This worked for me, for one of my mysql databases:

`backup_script [tab] /usr/bin/ssh user@example.com "/usr/bin/mysqldump --single-transaction -u username dbname" > dbname.sql [tab] example.com/mysql/`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is something to do with ssh. From the ssh man page

> ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred

You should use ssh -v[vv] to get a verbose output from ssh and see what it has to say.

Comment: So the issue is probably executing the command over SSH?

Comment: @TiffanyWalker: That's what it looks like just try ssh root@... and see what error you get or ssh -v[vv] ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up key authentication with the remote host, or is the ssh command expecting you to type in a password interactively?

If you haven't set up passwordless authentication, then the ssh command will fail to authenticate, and hence return an error (255 seems to be the default return value for any error).

Comment: It works fine. It copies the files, just the MySQL Backup part fails

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was solved by making sure that there *weren't* tabs in the script "path".

Instead of

```
backup_script [tab] /bin/ssh [tab] root@host.com [tab] "/usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot --all-databases > ./mysqldump.sql" [tab] ./mysql/
```

try

```
backup_script [tab] /bin/ssh root@host.com "/usr/bin/mysqldump -uroot --all-databases > ./mysqldump.sql" [tab] ./mysql/
```